# How to read from internal storage?

Tags: android, storage

If I have this:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
                String string = "hello world!";

                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    fos.write(string.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

What's the code to read that hello_file and put it in a normal string? I tried to find out myself with the dev website but I failed,it doesn't actually show anything and no website actually shows it how to read it... Please help!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to pass the absolete path and the file name. Try below

```
File image = new File("absolete path", "name of your file");
byte[] data = image.getPath().getBytes();
system.out.println(new String(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `InputStream` because you are doing reading not writing. Specify the new File instance with the file path and open the input stream, then use `StringBuilder` to get the data from the input stream and create string. Look around for examples if you are not familiar with `InputStream` and `File` class.